# Objective C - importing headers with same variable names

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a android game ready to launch and I'm currently working on porting it to iOS.

I'm fairly new to Objective C and C in general and I'm not sure exactly how @properties and @synthesize and #imports work.

My game shares a method file called gMain. This file includes the shared methods between objects. I have an object called Fish and in that object contains a method which requires the x,y value of another object called Fish2.

I'm unsure of how to access the variables when both Fish and Fish2 share the same variable names, int x, int y.

will this work?

```
//Fish.h 
@interface Fish 
{
     int x, y; 
} 
@property int x, y; 
-(void)blah;
@end  


//Fish2.h
@interface Fish2
{
    int x, y;
}
@property int x, y; 
@end    


//Fish.m 
#import Fish.h 
@implementation Fish  
@synthesize x, y;

-(void)blah
{
    x = Fish2.x;
    y = Fish2.y;
}
@end 


//Fish2.m
#import Fish2.h
@implementation Fish2
@synthesize x, y;
@end
```

Comment: It's pretty much like C++ classes -- instance variables and methods defined in two different classes are distinguished by the the type of the object pointer.  Properties are a special case of instance methods.  (The `@synthesize` statements must be inside an `@implementation` body for a given class, and hence one `@synthesize` cannot apply to two classes.)

Comment: And note that to reference a property of a class you must have a pointer to an *instance* of the class, not simply the class name.

Comment: (Are you familiar with Java?  If so, we could explain some of the concepts in terms of that language.)

Comment: As edited, your code is roughly valid (haven't gone over it with a fine-tooth comb).  You have two separate `@synthesize` statements, one for Fish and one for Fish2.  This recognizes that the x and y properties in Fish are totally distinct from the identically-named properties in Fish2.  The one obvious error in your code, as posted is the method `blah`, where you've used the class name Fish2 to reference properties in Fish2.  Properties relate to an *instance* of the object (just like an instance of a Java object), and hence you must supply an *instance* pointer to reference a property.

Comment: PS: If you think this is a snake pit, you haven't even gotten started!  You probably need to go back and pick up some fundamentals on object-oriented languages and memory management before you go much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are wanting to deal with a single class, with two instances, two separate classes. I'll try to give an example of each and try to explain what the code is doing.

### Single Class, Two Instances

**Fish.h**

```
@interface Fish : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int y;
- (void) someMethod;
@end
```

So you are defining a new object called FishA and the object has 2 public properties, x and y. The 2 items in parenthisis nonatomic and assign tell the compiler extra information about the properties. Bassicaly `nonatomic` means not to worry about thread safty and `assign` means that the property is a base type, not an object.

**Fish.m**

```
#import "Fish.h"

@implementation Fish
@synthesize x = _x;
@synthesize y = _y;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initilize default values
        // Only use the _x and _y in init
        // no other place
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) someMethod {
    // Set the values
    self.x = 10;
    self.y = 10;

    // Access the values
    NSLog(@"X: %d", self.x)
    NSLog(@"Y: %d", self.y)
}
```

So the `@synthesize` statments will create two methods for you, one to set the value and one to get the value. In the statements above the `x` tells the compiler to create the methods for the `x` property, the `_x` is the name of the interal storage variable for the property. It is much better that the property and the internal storage are separatly named, it makes the code cleaner and easier to understand whats going on.

In th `init` method we directly set the internal variable with the initial values. The `init` method is *generally* the only place you want to access the internal variables.

**Use**

```
#import "Fish.h"

- (void) example {
    Fish *fishA = [[Fish alloc] init];
    Fish *fishB = [[Fish alloc] init];

    fishA.x = 10;
    fishB.x = 20;

    [fishA someMethod];
    [fishB someMethod];
}
```

### Separate Classes

**FishA.h**

```
@interface FishA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int y;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int size;
- (void) someMethod;
@end
```

**FishA.m**

```
#import "FishA.h"

@implementation FishA
@synthesize x = _x;
@synthesize y = _y;
@synthesize size = _size;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initilize default values
        // Only use the _x and _y in init
        // no other place
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
        _size = 10;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) someMethod {
    // Set the values
    self.x = 10;
    self.y = 10;

    // Access the values
    NSLog(@"X: %d", self.x)
    NSLog(@"Y: %d", self.y)
}
```

**FishB.h**

```
@interface FishB : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int y;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSColor *color;
- (void) someMethod;
@end
```

The color propery looks a little different. Because color is an object and not a base type we need to tell the compiler how we want to handle it. The `strong` tells the compiler to hold on to this object untill we are done with it. The other option would be `weak` and that tells the compiler not to hold on to the object. Generally speaking, with objectes, use strong.

**FishB.m**

```
#import "FishB.h"

@implementation FishB
@synthesize x = _x;
@synthesize y = _y;
@synthesize color = _color;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initilize default values
        // Only use the _x and _y in init
        // no other place
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
        _color = [NSColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) someMethod {
    // Set the values
    self.x = 10;
    self.y = 10;

    // Access the values
    NSLog(@"X: %d", self.x)
    NSLog(@"Y: %d", self.y)
}
```

So I've created two separate classes, FishA has a size property and FishB has a color property. Both fish have the x and y properties. Not overly exciting but it makes the two classes different.

**Use**

```
#import "FishA.h"
#import "FishB.h"

- (void) example {
    FishA *fishA = [[FishA alloc] init];
    FishB *fishB = [[FishB alloc] init];

    fishA.x = 10;
    fishB.x = 20;

    fishA.size = 50; // Works
    fishB.size = 50; // Will not work

    fishA.color = [NSColor redColor]; // Will not work
    fishB.color = [NSColor redColor]; // Works
}
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much. This example was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> does this synthesize both xs and ys from the 2 objects?

**No.**

Your code won't compile. You've left out all the `@interface`, `@implementation`, and `@end` directives that tell the compiler what class you're talking about. A `@synthesize` directive will always be included between `@implementation *classname*` and `@end`, and it will only synthesize a property for the indicated class.

If you correct your code, the effect of the `@synthesize` should be obvious.

```
//Fish.h
@interface Fish
{
    int x, y;
}
@property int x, y;

@end

//Fish.m
#import Fish.h
#import Fish2.h       // it's not clear why you'd need this

@implementation Fish

@synthesize x, y;     // creates accessors for properties x and y of class Fish

@end
```

Comment: that isn't the actual code, i do hav the @interface and other syntax components.

how do you specify which classes to synthesize?

Comment: You should post the actual code, or at least something that compiles, because the answer to your question depends on it. @synthesize directives are part of a given class; see above.

Comment: edited code. Will [Fish blah] work? I don't have a mac available to me atm so I can't test it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider reading [about properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW17) as well as the rest of the Obj-C language guide. Realize that `Fish` is a class; before you access any properties you need to create an instance of that class: `Fish *fish = [[Fish alloc] init];` then you can say: `fish.x = 10` or `[fish setX:10]` or `int foo = [fish x];`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work

```
    -(void)blah
{
    x = Fish2.x;
    y = Fish2.y;
}
```

You need to create a pointer for Fish2. Something like this...

```
    -(void)blah
{
    Fish2 *selectedFish = //wherever the instance of the fish is.
    x = selectedFish.x;
    y = selectedFish.y;
}
```

If Fish creates an instance of fish2 maybe doing something like this would be more helpful.

```
    -(void)blahWithFish:(Fish2)currentFish
{
    x = currentFish.x;
    y = currentFish.y;
}
```

If you do something like that you can pass the fish to this method.

Also is there a reason for fish2? Are you not just creating 2 fish objects? Do they perform the same task? Maybe fish2 should inherit from Fish?

Does that help?